# Is there an intelligent PHP Emacs tagging solution?

Tags: php, emacs, tags

I want to navigate to a member declaration under the point. Creating a tag file using `etags *.php` and then navigating with `find-tag` is limited in that it doesn't seem to have any sense of the calling class. So you have to cycle if two classes have methods with the same name.

Semantic's `semantic-ia-fast-jump` function, another potential option, doesn't seem to work at all for PHP methods.

Comment: Maybe this link might be able to help you?
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags

Answer (score 2):

I have used this a time or two.

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

Try it out, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

For reference: There's some [php support for semantics wisent parser](https://github.com/emacsmirror/cedet/blob/master/contrib/wisent-php.el) now, so you should be able to use `semantic-ia-fast-jump` now.